# How to update server members cache?

Tags: javascript, caching, discord, discord.js

This is my code, it caches the members once, but never updates. How do I make it update?

```js
const list = bot.guilds.cache.get('Server id')
const members = list.members
list.members.cache.each(member => allUsers.push(member.user.id));
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [`GuildMemberManager.fetch()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMemberManager?scrollTo=fetch). This will cache all members (even the offline ones)

```js
await list.members.fetch()
list.members.cache.each(member =>
allUsers.push(member.user.id));
```